# SQLAlchemy Core - Subquery missing an alias

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I was working on a straightforward SQLAlchemy Core (Python 3.x) count unique query using the following code:

```
    table_object = sqlalchemy.Table(table_name, metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine, schema=schema)

    agg_fields = [get_column_correct_case(table_object, col) for col in agg_fields]
    agg_col_obj = [table_object.c[col] for col in agg_fields]

    agg_query = sqlalchemy.select(agg_col_obj).select_from(table_object)\
                        .group_by(*agg_fields).count()

    engine.scalar(agg_query)
```

While I believe this should be valid SQLAlchemy Core code, its execution returned a PYODBC error:

```
(pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]
Incorrect syntax near ')'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); 
[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

The SQL query generated by this code which failed to execute properly was:

```
[SQL: SELECT count([ACCOUNT]) AS tbl_row_count 
FROM (SELECT dbo.history.[ACCOUNT] AS [ACCOUNT], dbo.history.[RTXNNBR] AS [RTXNNBR] 
FROM dbo.history 
GROUP BY dbo.history.[ACCOUNT], dbo.history.[RTXNNBR])]
```

Running the query directly in SQL Server, it appears to be failing because the nested select is missing an alias. Is this a bug? If not, how do I fix this code?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. I was surprised it was necessary, but this can be resolved by giving the query to be counted an alias.

So

```
agg_query = sqlalchemy.select(agg_col_obj).select_from(table_object)\
                            .group_by(*agg_fields).count()
```

becomes:

```
agg_query = sqlalchemy.select(agg_col_obj).select_from(table_object)\
                    .group_by(*agg_fields).alias('a').count()
```

which now works.